# How To Implement Smooth Vertical Continuous Scroll When Clicked A Button

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm using Bootstrap 4 Modal and I've hidden the Overflow-Y (ScrollBar) to improve my design but at the same time, I have made a function with two buttons (Up & Down) using javascript to make navigation easier for every user. But the problem is that they are not automatic scrollable means the user has to click again and again to navigate up and down which is not good.

That's why I want to implement a system like a browser's default Up & Down scroll button which makes continuous scroll when a user presses the button for a long time.

Please see my gif image for better understanding, and give me your feedback it will be very useful for me, Thanks.

```js
                  var buttonDown = document.getElementById('btnDown');
                  var buttonUp = document.getElementById('btnUp');

                  buttonDown.onclick = function () {
                    document.getElementById('mo-body').scrollTop += 40;
                  };
                  buttonUp.onclick = function () {
                    document.getElementById('mo-body').scrollTop -= 40;
                  };
```

```css
.modal-body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}


.modal-body P {
  color: red;
}

.modal.left_modal .modal-dialog {
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  width: 450px;
  max-width: 85%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
      -ms-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
       -o-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
}

.modal.left_modal .modal-content {
  height: 100vh !important;
}

.modal.left_modal.fade .modal-dialog{
  left: -50%;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
}

.modal.left_modal.fade.show .modal-dialog{
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.modal_outer .modal-body {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    
    
<button class="btn  btn-primary  mt-3 float-right" id="modal_view_left" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#get_quote_modal">Open modal</button>



<div class="modal modal_outer left_modal fade" id="get_quote_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel2" >
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
          <h2 class="modal-title">LEFT MODAL</h2>
        </div>
        
        <div class="modal-body" id="mo-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 mb-4 mt-2">
               <div class="web-card" style="border: 3px solid red; border-radius: 15px;">
                  <div class="cards-inner">
                     <h3 class="text-center mt-3 mb-2">Sports Package</h3>
                        <hr class="card-hr">
                        <span class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3 mb-3">
                          <ul class="card-li">
                            <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                            <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                            <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                            <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                            <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                            <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                            <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                            <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                         </ul>
                        </span>
                        <hr class="card-hr">
                     <h3 class="text-center mt-2 mb-3">₹4,999/-</h3>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 mb-4">
               <div class="web-card" style="border: 3px solid red; border-radius: 15px;">
                  <div class="cards-inner">
                     <h3 class="text-center mt-3 mb-2">Library Package</h3>
                        <hr class="card-hr">
                        <span class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3 mb-3">
                           <ul class="card-li">
                              <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                              <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                              <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                              <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                              <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                              <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                              <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                              <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                           </ul>
                        </span>
                        <hr class="card-hr">
                     <h3 class="text-center mt-2 mb-3">₹9,999/-</h3>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 mb-2">
               <div class="web-card" style="border: 3px solid red; border-radius: 15px;">
                  <div class="cards-inner">
                     <h3 class="text-center mt-3 mb-2">Hostel Package</h3>
                        <hr class="card-hr">
                        <span class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3 mb-3">
                          <ul class="card-li">
                            <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                            <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                            <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                            <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                            <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                            <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                            <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                            <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                         </ul>
                        </span>
                        <hr class="card-hr">
                     <h3 class="text-center mt-2 mb-3">₹1,499/-</h3>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>  
         </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button id="btnDown" type="button" value="Down" class="btn btn-primary ml-auto">Down</button>
          <button id="btnUp" type="button" value="Up" class="btn btn-secondary mr-auto">Up</button>
        </div>

      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

][2]][2]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this.

```js
var buttonDown = document.getElementById('btnDown');
                  var buttonUp = document.getElementById('btnUp');

                  buttonDown.onclick = function () {
                    document.getElementById('mo-body').scrollTop += 40;
                      $("body, html").css("scroll-behavior", "smooth");
                  };
                  
                
                  
                  buttonUp.onclick = function () {
                    document.getElementById('mo-body').scrollTop -= 40;
                       $("body, html").css("scroll-behavior", "smooth")
                  };
```

```css
.modal-body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}


.modal-body P {
  color: red;
}

.modal.left_modal .modal-dialog {
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  width: 450px;
  max-width: 85%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
      -ms-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
       -o-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
}

.modal.left_modal .modal-content {
  height: 100vh !important;
}

.modal.left_modal.fade .modal-dialog{
  left: -50%;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
}

.modal.left_modal.fade.show .modal-dialog{
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.modal_outer .modal-body {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    
    
<button class="btn  btn-primary  mt-3 float-right" id="modal_view_left" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#get_quote_modal">Open modal</button>



<div class="modal modal_outer left_modal fade" id="get_quote_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel2" >
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
          <h2 class="modal-title">LEFT MODAL</h2>
        </div>
        
        <div class="modal-body" id="mo-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 mb-4 mt-2">
               <div class="web-card" style="border: 3px solid red; border-radius: 15px;">
                  <div class="cards-inner">
                     <h3 class="text-center mt-3 mb-2">Sports Package</h3>
                        <hr class="card-hr">
                        <span class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3 mb-3">
                          <ul class="card-li">
                            <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                            <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                            <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                            <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                            <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                            <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                            <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                            <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                         </ul>
                        </span>
                        <hr class="card-hr">
                     <h3 class="text-center mt-2 mb-3">₹4,999/-</h3>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 mb-4">
               <div class="web-card" style="border: 3px solid red; border-radius: 15px;">
                  <div class="cards-inner">
                     <h3 class="text-center mt-3 mb-2">Library Package</h3>
                        <hr class="card-hr">
                        <span class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3 mb-3">
                           <ul class="card-li">
                              <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                              <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                              <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                              <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                              <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                              <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                              <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                              <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                           </ul>
                        </span>
                        <hr class="card-hr">
                     <h3 class="text-center mt-2 mb-3">₹9,999/-</h3>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 mb-2">
               <div class="web-card" style="border: 3px solid red; border-radius: 15px;">
                  <div class="cards-inner">
                     <h3 class="text-center mt-3 mb-2">Hostel Package</h3>
                        <hr class="card-hr">
                        <span class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3 mb-3">
                          <ul class="card-li">
                            <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                            <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                            <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                            <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                            <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                            <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                            <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                            <li><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                         </ul>
                        </span>
                        <hr class="card-hr">
                     <h3 class="text-center mt-2 mb-3">₹1,499/-</h3>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>  
         </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button id="btnDown" type="button" value="Down" class="btn btn-primary ml-auto">Down</button>
          <button id="btnUp" type="button" value="Up" class="btn btn-secondary mr-auto">Up</button>
        </div>

      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```